# Select similar phrases in Microsoft Word

Tags: windows, find, microsoft-word-2010, highlighting

I need to select and highlight many sentences in which Microsoft Word in which the start word and the end word of the sentence/phrase is the same, but the content in between is different.

How can I achieve this using the find function in word? I want to automate doing this as it should be possible, only thing is I don't know how to achieve this. It would take a very long time for me to manually highlight so many phrases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular expressions.

Microsoft has [a tutorial here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx):

Comment: this i already know off but could you write the exact expression?

Comment: Let me try and figure it out. I don't quite have word available on the PC. It may be something along the lines of `(<*>)*\1` in their  [custom syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/putting-regular-expressions-to-work-in-word-HA001087304.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001087305) which is not the standard I'm good with

Comment: the worry is that all the characters that i'm trying to find are special characters so I'll need to escape them too I guess

Comment: I tested with my string above, but can't limit to once per line. Special chars can be [input or escaped](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm). Multi-highlight searches appear to be impossible without [VBA macros like this apparent solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321782/word-vba-find-and-highlight-matches). Either paste the code into a real shell outside Word with real regular expressions ([cygwin's bash](http://www.cygwin.com/) is useful but huge), or you'll need [VBA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn5iLnLQmYE). Sorry that I couldn't solve the issue.